# Kubernetes CronJob run every N hours not working

Tags: kubernetes, cron

I have a kubernetes cronjob object defined as follows:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: cloud-backup
  namespace: test-backup
spec:
  schedule: "0 */50 * * *"
.....
```

However, it's running every single day at 8pm which makes no sense to me. Isn't this cron format configured to run once every 50 hours? I'm using this exact cron schedule in a concourse pipeline at it runs when expected there so not sure what I'm missing.

Thanks!

Comment: [the schedule seems correct](https://crontab.guru/#0_*/50_*_*_*)

Comment: No it doesn't, the 50 becomes truncated to the max value of 23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cron expression allows certain values per field. For the hour field the values 0-23 are allowed. (See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#schedule-syntax )

If you want to achieve something that does not run in an interval that can be expressed using the cron expressions you might want to have a cronjob that runs once per hour and uses a configmap to store the execution state and schedule a regular job programmatically.

Comment: Did you have time to check my answer? Did it answer your question? If yes, please consider accepting and upvoting it, which might help other community members with similar issues.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! Although the confusing part is I was able to use that exact cron syntax in a concourse pipeline and it worked without issues. So for this cronjob, I just changed it to run once every 3 days instead of every 50 hours since my use case allowed for that.